# Load Large Image on SDCard into a small imageview in a custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-bitmap

i have a custom listview [like this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-swlVxU_S-Jo/UOxRcqXl7aI/AAAAAAAAAtk/4a5r_rJFaMg/s1600/a1.png). in my application i can open the camera and capture photos onto the sdcard. i want to display the captured photos in the small imageview. but i became the following message: **Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2448x3264, max=2048x204)** 
how can i display an image like that in a imageview, which has for example a layout width/height 90x90dip and 50X50dip?

thanks in advance

**EDIT 1:**

```
cursor = myDBHandler.getAllDifferentNames1();

    String[] dbColm = new String[] {"n", "d", "p"};

    int[] toList = new int[] {R.id.txt_name, R.id.date, R.id.list_userImage};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter 
            = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                        (this, R.layout.listrow, cursor, dbColm , toList );

    mainList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

Comment: go thru this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: hi padma, thank you for your advice. in my case, it is a little bit complicated because i am working with a simplecursor adapter and i dont know, how to scale down the image. see my edit padma

Comment: create your custom adapter and set your image with mImageView.setImageBitmap(
    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));

Answer (score 2):

You can scale your image using **Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()**. here I am giving you a procedure...follow this...I think you will get rid of your problem.

```
private Bitmap scaleImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    //required image width and height
    int reqImageWidth = 90; //as you mentioned
    int reqImageHeight = 90; //as you mentioned

    /*Different device has different display density. If you want to show your  
     * image with same layout_width and layout_height then you should multiply   
     *something with yourrequired width and height to bring your image in balance.*/
    float multiplier = getMultiplierFromDeviceDensity();

    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, (int) (reqImageWidth * multiplier),
                              (int) (reqImageHeight * multiplier), false);
}

private float getMultiplierFromDeviceDensity() {

    int d = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    float multiplier = 0f;
    switch (d) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        multiplier = 0.8f;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        multiplier = 1.0f;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        multiplier = 1.2f;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        multiplier = 1.5f;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
        multiplier = 2.0f;
        break;
    }
    return multiplier;
}
```